# React : Invalid hook in a class-based component that doesn't use a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

I have some issues with React. I want to create a component library in the form of a class (I come from the Java world and I find the OOP more readable).

For that, I made a base class from which all of my components will inherit.

```
import { Box, createMuiTheme, Theme } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import { MyTheme, defaultPalette } from '../MyTheme/MyTheme';
import { BoxProps } from './BoxProps';
import { MyComponentProperties, MyComponentState } from './MyComponent.types';
import { ComponentUtilities } from './ComponentUtilities';
import { EventListenerPool } from './EventListenerPool';

/**
 * Default class for create a Component with this library
 * @abstract
 */
export abstract class
  MyComponent<P extends MyComponentProperties, S extends MyComponentState>
  extends React.Component<P, S> {

  static readonly VERSION: number = 100;

  /**
   * Constant for the event : componentDidMount
   * @constant EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT
   */
  protected static readonly EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT = 'EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT';
  /**
   * Constant for the event : componentWillUnmount
   * @constant EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT
   */
  protected static readonly EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT = 'EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT';
  /**
   * Constant for the event : clickOutside
   * @constant EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE
   */
  protected static readonly EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE = 'EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE';

  /**
   * Listener's pool for trigger events
   * @type {Map<string, EventListenerPool>}
   */
  private readonly eventListenerPools: Map<string, EventListenerPool>;
  /**
   * Component theme
   * @property {Theme}
   */
  protected readonly theme: Theme;
  /**
   * Generic id if the property's id is missing
   * @type {string}
   */
  private genericId: string = ComponentUtilities.getNewGenericMyComponentId();
  /**
   * Root node in the DOM
   * @type {Element | null | Text} 
   */
  protected rootNode: Element | null | Text;

  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param props Properties for create the component
   */
  constructor(props: P) {
    super(props);
    this.rootNode = null;
    this.state = {} as unknown as S;
    this.eventListenerPools = new Map<string, EventListenerPool>();
    this.initComponentListeners();
    this.theme = this.createTheme();
  }

  /**
   * Get component's ID
   * @returns ID property or the generic ID
   */
  get id(): string {
    let id = this.props.id;
    if (id === undefined) {
      id = this.genericId;
    }

    return id as string;
  }

  /**
   * Get style for the component
   * @returns component style
   */
  protected get style(): React.CSSProperties | undefined {
    return this.props.style;
  }

  /**
   * Get disabled property
   * @returns true if the component is disabled
   */
  get isDisabled(): boolean | undefined {
    return this.props.disabled;
  }

  /**
   * Get component's class name
   * @returns Class name
   */
  protected get className(): string | undefined {
    return this.props.className;
  }

  /**
   * Get component's children
   * @returns children
   */
  protected get children(): React.ReactNode | undefined {
    return this.props.children;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new pool listner for specific event type
   * @param eventType Event type
   */
  protected createEventListenerPool(eventType: string): void {
    this.eventListenerPools.set(eventType, new EventListenerPool());
  }

  /**
   * Get the listener pool which is associated with the type of event
   * @param eventType Event type
   * @returns listener pool or undefined if the pool isn't created
   */
  private getEventListenerPool(
    eventType: string
  ): EventListenerPool | undefined {
    return this.eventListenerPools.get(eventType);
  }

  /**
   * Add a new listener in a listener pool
   * @param eventType Event type
   * @param listener Listener to add
   */
  protected addListenerInListenerPool(eventType: string | Array<string>,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    listener?: Function): void {
    if (listener) {
      const pools = new Array<EventListenerPool>();

      if (eventType instanceof Array) {
        eventType.forEach((event) => {
          const pool = this.getEventListenerPool(event);
          if (pool) {
            pools.push(pool);
          }
        });

      } else {
        const listenerPool = this.getEventListenerPool(eventType);
        if (listenerPool) {
          pools.push(listenerPool);
        }
      }

      pools.forEach((pool) => pool.add(listener));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Basic method for fire an event
   * @param eventType Event type key
   * @param event Event to fire
   */
  protected fireBasicEventType(eventType: string, event?: unknown): void {
    const listenerPool = this.getEventListenerPool(eventType);

    if (listenerPool) {
      listenerPool.fireEvent(event);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initialize component listeners
   */
  protected initComponentListeners(): void {
    this.createEventListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT);
    this.addComponentDidMountListener(this.props.onComponentDidMount);
    this.createEventListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT);
    this.addComponentWillUnmountListener(this.props.onComponentWillUnmount);
    this.createEventListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE);
    this.addClickOutsideListener(this.props.onClickOutside);
  }

  /**
   * Add a listener when the component did mount
   * @param listener Listener
   */
  private addComponentDidMountListener(listener?: (() => void)): void {
    this.addListenerInListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT, listener);
  }

  /**
   * Function called when component did mount.
   * Add a default listener on mousedown event for manage the click outside the component
   */
  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.rootNode = findDOMNode(this);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this));
    this.fireBasicEventType(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_DID_MOUNT);
  }

  /**
   * Add a listener when the component will unmount
   * @param listener Listener
   */
  private addComponentWillUnmountListener(listener?: (() => void)): void {
    this.addListenerInListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT, listener);
  }

  /**
   * Add a listener when click outside the component
   * @param listener Listener
   */
  private addClickOutsideListener(listener?: ((event: MouseEvent) => void)): void {
    this.addListenerInListenerPool(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE, listener);
  }

  /**
   * Function called when the component will unmount
   */
  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this));
    this.fireBasicEventType(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_WILL_UNMOUNT);
  }

  /**
   * Create the theme for the component
   * @returns Theme for the component
   */
  protected createTheme(): Theme {
    return createMuiTheme(this.defaultComponentTheme());
  }

  /**
   * Get the default theme for the component
   * @returns Default theme
   */
  private defaultComponentTheme(): MyTheme {
    return defaultPalette;
  }

  /**
   * The render for the React component. Wrap the compoent's render.
   * @returns The element that will be used in the DOM
   */
  render(): JSX.Element {
    let element: JSX.Element;

    element = this.renderComponent();
    element = this.wrapElement(element);

    return element;
  }

  /**
   * The method for render compnent. Return only the component's render
   * @returns Element will be used in the DOM for the component
   */
  protected abstract renderComponent(): JSX.Element;

  /**
   * Wrap the element with a Box component
   * @param oriElement Element to wrap
   * @returns Wrapped element
   */
  protected wrapElement(oriElement: JSX.Element): JSX.Element {
    let element = oriElement;
    const { boxProps } = this.props;
    element = this.wrapWithBoxProps(element, boxProps);
    return element;
  }

  protected wrapWithBoxProps(oriElement: JSX.Element, boxProps?: BoxProps): JSX.Element {
    let element = oriElement;

    if (boxProps) {
      element = (
        <Box {...boxProps}>
          {element}
        </Box>
      );
    }

    return element;
  }

  /**
   * Handle the event when click outside the element.
   * Fire event only if the mousedown event is outside the component
   * @param event The event mousedown
   */
  protected handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.childOf(event.target as Element | null)) {
      this.fireBasicEventType(MyComponent.EVENT_COMPONENT_CLICK_OUTSIDE, event);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check if the element is in the component (in the DOM)
   * @param node Node to check
   * @returns true if the element is in the component DOM
   */
  protected childOf(node: (Node & ParentNode) | null) {
    let child = node;
    let check = false;
    while (child !== null) {
      if (child === this.rootNode) {
        check = true;
        break;
      }
      child = child.parentNode;
    }
    return check;
  }
}
```

Then I have a basic component to display an alert for example.

```
import { Alert, AlertTitle } from '@material-ui/lab';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from '../MyComponent/MyComponent';
import { MyAlertProperties, MyAlertState } from './MyAlert.types';

/**
 * An alert displays a short, important message in a way that attracts the user's attention without interrupting the user's task.
 * @extends MyComponent
 */
export class MyAlert extends MyComponent<MyAlertProperties, MyAlertState> {

  static readonly VERSION: number = 100;

  /**
   * @override
   */
  protected renderComponent(): JSX.Element {
    const { elevation, severity, variant } = this.props;
    const element = (
      <Alert
        elevation={elevation}
        variant={variant}
        severity={severity}
      >
        {this.getRenderTitle()}
        {this.children}
      </Alert>
    );

    return element;
  }

  /**
   * Render the alert's title
   * @returns Alert's title element
   */
  private getRenderTitle(): JSX.Element {
    const { title } = this.props;
    let element = undefined as unknown as JSX.Element;
    if (title) {
      element = (<AlertTitle>{title}</AlertTitle>);
    }

    return element;
  }

}
```

I have built my library with rollupjs and it works great via storybook.

Then I want to associate my library with an npm dependency ina React application, which I created previously via "create-react-app", with the typescript template. In the App.tsx, I call my component and I get the following error message "Invalid hook call" while I am not using any in my component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyAlert } from 'myreactlib/build';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MyAlert>Alert</MyAlert>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

If I use a simple div, my App.tsx is working fine.

I don't understand where my problem may be coming from. I don't use a hook. I know it's forbidden in class-based component.
For information, the version of react on my application seems to be good :

- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1

If someone has an idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Hooks also refers to the life cycles hooks : componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate etc... It is easy to confuse them with function component hooks

Comment: goto1 I have already looked at the link which is in the disclaimer. Nam Bui I removed the willUnount and didMount functions but no better.  Before this library worked when I created it with create-react-app + copy of the sources in final application (I changed the build of my library so that the structure is closer to a real library and not an application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have duplicated instances of React in your app, which can generate this misleading error message. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991

Make sure React is a peer dependency and you are not bundling it in your library, and you are not using your library via `npm link`.

Comment: I looked over my two projects with the npm ls command. I have each time an instance of react and react-dom. I'm going to look at the article you told me. I'll see if I can find a fix

Comment: I don't use npm link for install my library. I use npm install with the relative path

Comment: Good I managed to make my dependency function thanks to the following link:  [https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-673539558](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-673539558). Thank you so much